# Best Practise: How to protect user specific files in a web-folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cookies

I have a website with different user groups. Each user group has different pages they can access. These pages can contain links to files (documents, pdf, etc.). Each group should now be able to access only their documents in the group-specific folder.

What is the best practise to make this work? Following things came up:

- Generate a Hash of all uploaded files and name the file according to the hash, so that it can't be found by
  trying and restrict displaying of directory. (Problem: Links can be shared and files would be accessible by public)
- Restrict Access with .htaccess file (Problem: User must type in a password each time and the cms can be linked to the .htaccess file - not dynamic)
- Check if cookie exists with .htaccess e.g. http://www.willmaster.com/blog/contentprotection/htaccess-cookie.php (Problem: not dynamic if I create new user groups)

What is the best solution for this problem? Is it any of the mentioned?

Comment: Move them outside of the web folder

Comment: and how am I supposed to access them and upload via cms? furthermore the groups wouldn't be dynamic either.

Comment: If you move the files outside the web folder, then you have a `fileAccess` script inside your web-folder that verifies that a user is permitted access to the file that they've requested before sending it to their browser via `readfile()`

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to upload files with a CMS to a non-accessible location? Is it possible to edit this fileAccess file according to the groups created in the CMS? I don't think so?!

Comment: Yes it's perfectly possible, uploaded files can be placed anywhere within the server filesystem that the webserver user has access to, not simply under the web root

Answer (score 1):

What I did was wrapping the files in a dynamic script with access control:

```
if ($userIsLoggedIn)
{
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$filenameOfPDF.'"');
  header('Pragma: public');
  readfile($pathToPDF);
}
else echo 'You do not have access';
```

This is written in PHP. The file itself is stored in a directory which is not accessible from the web.

The only disatvantage is that you would need to do this for every file type. If only access is important you could generalize:

```
if ($userIsLoggedIn)
{
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
  header('Pragma: public');
  readfile($path);
}
else echo 'You do not have access';
```

But I am sure there are other solutions.

Comment: Thank you already for your input! is it possible to upload files with a CMS to a non-accessible location?

Comment: If your CMS is webbased then you can make a directory which is accessible to the CMS, but not to anything else. See the manual of your particular CMS. This will vary from CMS to CMS, so no general answer can be given.